# C++: Why priority queue has no back() function?

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue

According to the cppreference website on `priority_queue`:

> Container -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer, and its iterators must satisfy the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator. Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual semantics:
> front()
> push_back()
> pop_back()
> The standard containers std::vector and std::deque satisfy these requirements.

and "C++ Primer, 5th Edition" by Stanley Lipmann:

> q.back()    Only valid for queue

Since cppreference states that `priority_queue` (container adaptor) requires `front()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()`, why is `q.back()` only valid for `queue` and not for `priority_queue`? If you look at cppreference for `priority_queue`, there's no function `back()` for it.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is a heap-like data structure. It is not similar to a `std::queue`. What do you expect `back()` and `front()` (which it also doesn't have) to refer to and how would you use them?

Comment: Because `back()` is pointless in a priority queue container adapter. It would not guarantee delivery of the inverse priority element (aka the smallest element in a max heap, or the greatest element in a minheap). Nor would it deliver the last-inserted element. A priority queue has no concept of `back`, so there is no reason to provide it.

Comment: @user17732522 It does not have front() but why then the requirement states it requires front() on the underlying data structure to build it

Comment: @yapkm01 Because the implementation of `priority_queue` will use `front()` on the underlying container to give you the [`top()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top). It needs to give you that first element somehow...

Comment: @WhozCraig So it does not have the concept of front() & back(). But it requires underlying data structure front() to build it? Weird?

Comment: @Barry Think top() does not mean front() (??) The max element could be in the middle. top() just return the max element. Selection is based on priority.

Comment: *"The max element could be in the middle"* - did you miss the part about this managing a *heap* ? A binary minmax heap doesn't keep it's max-element "in the middle".

Comment: @user4581301 No. Let me put it simply. Priority Queue requires underlying data structure requirement to build it - namely front()/push_back()/pop_back(). After Priority Queue been built there is no function back() ON the Priority Queue itself. Why?

Comment: @yapkm01 -- What would `back()` return?  Imagine you had to write the documentation for your proposed `back()` function for priority_queue.

Comment: What do you mean "after"? The adapter *always* manages the underlying container. On every push and pop operation.

Comment: @WhozCraig Does that means this site tutorial is wrong https://www.javatpoint.com/priority-queue-in-cpp? Check it out there. It clearly shows max is not always the on the front. Haven't dive deep into Priority Queue on heaps yet.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it means available function for priority queue instance itself. there is no back()

Comment: @yapkm01 But what does this `back()` function return?  The item with the least priority?

Comment: The fact it shows 4 *in the middle* doesn't mean that's how the container adapter orders it. All the examples keep things in *insertion order*, not priority. Either because the author wanted to contrast it with a FIFO queue, or because they don't really understand how a priority queue is implemented. Seems like a rather poor tutorial site, on the whole.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok. i see your point. So there's no front() & back() function for priority queue. Why does the requirement needs pop_back() on the underlying DS to build it? I understand why it needs push_back(). But not pop_back().

Comment: @user4581301 understood. Just curious .. why does it needs pop_back() on the backing container?

Comment: @yapkm01 -- It needs `pop_back` because internally, behind the scenes, that's what is required to maintain the underlying data structure.  How it uses `pop_back()` shouldn't be your concern.

Comment: Take some time to look at the min-heap and/or max-heap data structures. The requirements will make more sense when you see how elements are added or removed from those data structures.

Comment: Also, if you truly want to know the highest and lowest priority, maybe a min-max heap would be what you're looking for.  The problem is that there is no standard min-max heap in C++ (just min heap and max heap, not a combination of them).

Answer (score 1):

`priority_queue` keeps the elements in a partially sorted state. The point of the structure is that it allows you to pull elements out in sorted order. Since the elements are only partially sorted the `back()` is not well defined. To maintain a `back()` pointer additional storage, or a different data structure would be required. Since this is typically not needed the standard opted for the simpler implementation.

If you try to do this with an array or vector, the naive approach is O(N) per insertion(find the right position then shift all larger values one place), while the `priority_queue` keeps it a O(logN). If you have all the elements from the start, putting them in a vector and sorting is better (there are less swaps and could have better cache consistency compared to `priority_queue`, on average, but they are both O(NlogN)).

If you really need `back()` look for a min-max heap.